# Expression correct for polynomials inside a mixed model?

Tags: mixed-model

I'm asking for the mathematically correct formulation when using polynomials of 3rd degree for the fixed and as well as for the random effects of a linear mixed model:

[image: formula]

I wonder, if the polynomials are the same for the fixed and random effects. As the fixed and random effects get dedicated estimators I assume the corresponding polynomials are not the same. To be precise, I believe it must be:

[image: formula2]

The index of gamma changed here.
Can you please help me to understand the precise expression? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mathematical formulation of a linear mixed models with a 3-rd degree polynomial in both the fixed- and random-effects parts will be:

$$\left\{
\begin{array}{}
y_{ij} = (\beta_0 + b_{i0}) + (\beta_1 + b_{i1}) x_{ij} + (\beta_2 + b_{i2}) x_{ij}^2 + (\beta_3 + b_{i3}) x_{ij}^3 + \varepsilon_{ij},\\\\
b_i \sim \mathcal N(0, D), \quad \varepsilon_{ij} \sim \mathcal N(0, \sigma^2), \quad i = 1, \ldots, n, \quad j = 1, \ldots, n_i,
\end{array}
\right.$$

where $\beta^\top = (\beta_0, \beta_1, \beta_2, \beta_3)$ denotes the fixed-effects vector, $b_i^\top = (b_{i0}, b_{i1}, b_{i2}, b_{i3})$ denotes the random-effects vector for subject $i$, and $D$ is the $4 \times 4$ variance-covariance matrix of these random effects.

Comment: ah, ok.. so it seems my lecturer added the "p-"letters only for a better understanding. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, can you please answer me another question? The expectation value of the random effects is zero as well as the expectation value of the errors. An expectation value of the fixed effects does not make sense, right?

Comment: Under a maximum likelihood framework they are parameters and don’t have a distribution.